# Timezone change in Moment timezone module

Tags: node.js, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to set the timezone for Date string in NodeJS. The module for this is Moment Timezone.

As from the docs:

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
moment.tz.add('America/Los_Angeles|PST PDT|80 70|0101|1Lzm0 1zb0 Op0');

var m = moment.tz("2013-11-18 11:55", "America/Los_Angeles");
m.format();                     // 2013-11-18T11:55:00-08:00
console.log(m);
```

But I've got the 2013-11-18T19:55:00.000Z.

When I want to get something like 2013-11-18 11:55:00 GMT -0800. What's up? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're logging the moment instance `m` instead of the output string from `m.format()`

Everything else looks fine.

You may also want to read about [internal properties](http://momentjs.com/guides/#/lib-concepts/internal-properties/) in the moment user guides, and Maggie's blog post, ["Moment.JS Shows the Wrong Date!"](https://maggiepint.com/2016/05/14/moment-js-shows-the-wrong-date/)

Comment: Thanks! So can this be used for overriding Date constructor? I want to set the resulting string as the PageMod on NodeJS for override date.

Comment: Or Moment Timezone is NOT for overriding Date? Do you know other ways to set GMT on Date string constructor on NodeJS?

Comment: Please follow [StackOverflow Guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help).  In particular, please don't ask new questions using comments.  Just ask a new question.  Also, please search first, and I suggest you read the moment docs as well.  Cheers.